# What is a good way to proceed to store and use sensitive data in prod environment?

Tags: python, django, security

I have a django web app in a production environment hosted on a server. To store sensitive data I am using a `.env` file excluded from my git process stored on the server where my app is hosted.

```
# .env file

{
    "ENV_TYPE": "prod",
    "SECRET_KEY": "mysecretkey",
    "ALLOWED_HOSTS":[
        "somewhere.com"
    ],
    "DEBUG": false,
    "STATIC_ROOT": "/somewhere/staticfiles",
    "DATABASES": {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "NAME": "databaseName",
        "USER": "username",
        "PASSWORD": "myPassword",
        "HOST": "somewhereelse.com"
        }
    }
}
```

And in my app I get back data like this in `setting.py` for instance:

```
# setting.py
# Get back non secret env data such as DEBUG, ALLOWED HOSTS
with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env'), 'r') as f:
    env_data = json.load(f)

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env_data["SECRET_KEY"]

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = env_data["DEBUG"]

ALLOWED_HOSTS = env_data["ALLOWED_HOSTS"]
```

Do you believe this is a good way to proceed ? Indeed I still have somewhere on my server some passwords that are hard coded.

Comment: storing passwords in files usually is a bad idea - malicious system user may get access to them, and sometimes compromised services reveal them even remotely. But - if you carefully store file, maintain strict permissions and overall good security posture of your assets, it may be pretty reliable solution. If data protected by those passwords are not extremely sensitive, probably you could store password in your files. Just carefully consider possible attacks on those files. If data are very sensitive, you should consider using more secure solutions (vaults, TPM, central key management).

Comment: Ok many thanks for your detailed answer. I also rely on the security provided by host server platform.